# How to convert custom digits to date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming 421 stands for April 2021 and 1299 for December 1999, what would be the correct formula to convert the digits in to the corresponding date format in excel?

Comment: Do you want an actual date? If so you need a day number too; you can't get a date from just a month and year.

Comment: How would you differentiate December 2050 or 1950 when you got 1250?

Comment: @BigBen  You are correct!

Comment: April 2021 is in the future -- are you sure the data you are looking at contains data in the future? Or is it all historical? If it is historical, then my answer would be the correct solution, but if the data is in the future then, VBasic2008 would have the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `30` as you see fit:

```
=IFERROR(DATE(IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))<30,2000+RIGHT(A1,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, here is a one-liner (note, to get the correct century ***the formula is posted lower in the answer*** and is more complicated):

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1)
```

`DATE` requires 1) Year 2) Month and 3) Day

1. So, it's easy to get the year (just take the two most digits)
2. However, it's trickier to get the month, since it can be 3 or 4 digits, so you need some if logic to add a 0 in front if only 3 digits and THEN take the left two digits to extract the month.
3. Finally, you have to have a day for the formula, so just put a 1. Then format the cells as desired to whatever date format. See screenshot.

[image]

In order to get the correct century, then the formula gets complicated :) Basically, it says if the date is greater than now, subtract a century. If it is less than now, then go with that date.

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1))+100,MONTH(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1)),DAY(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1)))>NOW(),DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1),DATE(YEAR(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1))+100,MONTH(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1)),DAY(DATE(RIGHT(A1,2),LEFT(IF(LEN(A1)=3,0&A1,A1),2),1))))
```

[image]

Comment: So with this formula 920 becomes 01.09.1920, but I need September 2020. I don't have any dates before 1980...

Comment: Good points, see updates! My answer makes the assumption that all dates are in the past and within the last century.

Comment: @senheisen did this get you what you were looking for?